# sound in FreeBSD 11 up suddenly down suddenly

Tags: freebsd, audio, audio-volume

i'm coming from linux i installed freebsd 11 xfced all things is right but i have some problem not dangrous, the most important is sound when i installed xfce4-volumed some people told me that isn't correct to install xfce4-volume,i removed it but know when i up or down the sound it did it suddenly.
sorry about my language maybe i dosn't clair the problem 
i mean when i make the sound up it delay .. takes some second to do it
sorry about my language maybe i dosn't clair the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly if this is the main reason, but after I installed lxde, I'm now using function keys to control the volume and the problem is solved.